# Why does Netbeans navigator pane not populate javascript files with specific filenames?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, netbeans-8.1

While I admit this is a pretty obscure problem, I'm posting this partly in case it is driving others crazy (too), partly because it might have wider ramifications, and partly because it may be an issue with my project settings.

In NB-8.1 I have several angular modules for handling a configuration-editing app. Since last week I have been trying to figure out why the navigator pane doesn't populate with these files. When I click on the source, the Navigator pane doesn't update. If the pane is newly opened, it shows `<No view available>`. If it is correctly showing another file, it remains showing the old file and effectively ignores the new file.

After experimenting, I found that it is specific to any js file with a filename prefix of "config" - which in this case was all the files for this particular app (config-service.js, config-ctrl.js, etc). Renaming the files with a new prefix (eg, "konfig-ctrl.js" or "x-config-ctrl.js") solved the issue.

Is this widespread, or a problem only with this project? If the latter, what should I look for? Help or advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug to me. AFAIK NetBeans is handling JS files with the config in name as possible Karma configurations and maybe it (although I can't remember if Karma has to be enabled or where exactly does it look for these candidate files...) I'd suggest to report a bug against NetBeans https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=web (component HTML Project)

Comment: Thanks @ladar. Do you use NB-8.1? If so, can you duplicate this? Yes, I have raised a bug [https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257617] (component Navigation - HTML Project wasn't an option??)

Comment: Thank you, I can reproduce it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I get a very similiar problem.  Any js file with "conf" in the name (anywhere in the name) cannot be Run as javascript from Netbeans.  Right-click on the file and Run is deactivated.  Once I change the name to something else, it works.